# Why does calling random() inside of a case statement produce unexpected results?

Tags: postgresql, random, case

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2463d5a8ee2849a6e1f5

Query 1 does not produce the expected results. However, queries 2 and 3 do. Why does moving the call to random() outside of the case statement matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the first expression:

```
select (case when round(random()*999999) + 1 between 000001 and 400000 then 1
             when round(random()*999999) + 1 between 400001 and 999998 then 2
             when round(random()*999999) + 1 between 999999 and 999999 then 3
             else 4
        end)
from generate_series(1, 8000000)
```

Presumably, you are thinking that the value "4" should almost never be selected.  But, the problem is that `random()` is being called separately for each `when` clause.

So, the chance the it fails each clause is independent:

- About 60% of the time a random number will not match "1".
- About 40% of the time a random number will not match "2".
- About 99.9999% of the time a random number will not match "3" (I apologize if the number of nines is off, but the value is practically 1).

That means that about 24% of the time (60% * 40% * 99.9999%), the value "4" will appear.  In actual fact, the first query returns "4" 23.98% of the time.  To be honest, this is very close to the actual value, but given this size of data, but it is a bit further off than I would expect.  However, it is close enough to explain what is happening.